# Exponent Problem - How do I approach this question:$x^{m+2}\cdot x^{-2m}\cdot x^{m-5}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Assume all variable exponents represent positive integers, and simplify each integer.

$$x^{m+2}\cdot x^{-2m}\cdot x^{m-5}$$

Comment: Can you confirm if you mean the following: $x^{m} + 2\cdot x^{-2m}\cdot x^{m-5}$? Or do you mean $x^{m+2}\cdot x^{-2m}\cdot x^{m-5}$?  Or even perhaps $x^m + 2\cdot x^{-2}\cdot m\cdot x^m - 5$?  Parenthesis are important if you aren't able to properly write super/subscripts

Comment: Penultimate expression.

Comment: In general $x^a\cdot x^b=x^{a+b}$.

Comment: what do you mean of x^m+2 * x^-2m*x^m-5? please use of parentheses.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I will assume for the moment that you intend the question to be $x^{m+2}\cdot x^{-2m}\cdot x^{m-5}$

Remember an important property of exponents.

> $$x^a \cdot x^b = x^{a+b}$$

This generalizes further from induction

> $$x^a \cdot x^b \cdot \dots \cdot x^k = x^{a+b+\dots+k}$$

So, $$x^{m+2}\cdot x^{-2m}\cdot x^{m-5} = x^{(m+2)+(-2m)+(m-5)}=x^{-3}$$